# Delete from the next character till EOL

Tags: cut-copy-paste, cursor-motions

## My problem

Consider the following line:

[image]

I have just pasted `@SrvrlessDaysTLVtlv` before `tlv@serverlessdays.io`, and I'd like to delete anything from the small-case `t` till EOL.

## What have I tried

- `d$` deletes from the `V` till EOL, not from the `t`
- Read about motions, found nothing about deleting from the *next* character

## My question

**What is the right motion (for delete or yank) from the *next* cursor, not from the current one?**

Comment: You might want to edit your question with some example data instead of your actual endpoints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest and quickest solution is to move the cursor of one character to the right (with <kbd>l</kbd> or <kbd>right</kbd> or <kbd>space</kbd>) and then delete until the end of the line with <kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>$</kbd> which is the same thing)

> <kbd>l</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>

You'll end up on the end of the line so moving the cursor is not that bad and you still have only two key to stroke.